# ansible - using array of Variables and loop through it

Tags: loops, ansible

I have to run steps like this around 20-25 times. How can I do with for loop (with_items).

I can have the the parameters URL1, Location1, pkg1.comamd1, $pkg1.command2 are pre defined and I can have them defined in the ansible play book. the Pkg1 value will be passed from the jenkins script

```
- get_url:
    url: "$URL1"
    dest: $Location1
  when: $Pkg1 != 'NONE' 
- Name : run the commands
  Shell: sh $pkg1.comamd1; sh $pkg1.command2
  when: Pkg1 != 'NONE'
```

how can I create an array of variables and do it with_items

```
VarDetails {Pkg1, URL1, Location1, comamd1a, $command1b
            Pkg2, URL2, Location2, comamd2a, $command2b
            Pkg3, URL3, Location3, comamd3a, $command3b
            ....................
            ....................
            }
```

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Start with [Creating valid variable names](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested but it must work with below reference example while using list of items.

```
- name: more complex items to add several users
  user:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    uid: "{{ item.uid }}"
    groups: "{{ item.groups }}"
    state: present
  with_items:
     - { name: testuser1, uid: 1002, groups: "wheel, staff" }
     - { name: testuser2, uid: 1003, groups: staff }
```

dont forget to add item before your variables by changing

```
url: "$URL1"
dest: $Location1
```

to

```
url: "item.url"
dest: "item.location"
```

and while referencing in with_items.. use your variable $URL1, $URL2